# how to make this java script run in my form?

Tags: javascript, html

When the people fill my from, I want them to use an enter button like a tab button to fill all the form.  So i have put javascript code into my form.  But it doesn't work.... 
Can someone tell me why this code didn't work?  I use internet explorer 9, Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox to try it, but doesn't work also...

```
    <!--<html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function noenter() {
  if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13);
  myform.submit();
  else
    return true;}
 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="berjaya.php" onSubmit="return submitOK">
  <table width="35%" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Please fill the form bellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="21%">first name</td>
      <td width="2%">:</td>
      <td width="77%"><label>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" name="fname" id="fname">

      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>last name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" name="lname" id="lname">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>age</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" name="age" id="age">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>date of birth</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" name="dobirth" id="dobirth">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>home town</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" name="htown" id="htown"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><label>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"  onClick="submitOK=true">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>-->
```

Comment: `submitOK` isn't defined, `noenter` makes no sense and will submit the form anyway instead of acting like a tab and therefore mirrors the same functionality. You're using tables for layout with deprecated `width` attributes that are arbitrary percentages, etcetera. Ask a *specific* question please.

Comment: how i can make the java script working? can u tell me what should i do for the code to make it working like i want?

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd actually bothered to READ that JavaScript you've copypastaed into your form, you'd reliaze that it actually TRIGGERS the form submission anytime the enter key is pressed on any of your input boxes.

If you want to disable the enter key, then you have to return `false`, not do `form.submit()`.

Comment: can u tell me which part of the code i need to change to make it working?thank you so much for your reply..